# Thread safety of std::shared_ptr<std::mutex>

Tags: c++, thread-safety

Consider the following `class` with a `shared_ptr` data object. The purpose is to obtain cheaply copyable objects with a data cache shared among the copies.

```
#include <memory> // std::shared_ptr
#include <mutex> // std::mutex, std::lock_guard

class DataClass {

  std::shared_ptr<DataType> data;
  std::shared_ptr<std::mutex> data_lock;

public:
  DataClass() : data(std::make_shared<DataType>()), data_lock(std::make_shared<std::mutex>()) {}

  DataType get_data() const {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock_guard(*data_lock);
    if (/* data not cached */) {
      /* calculate and store data */
    }
    return *data;
  }
};
```

Are calls to `get_data()` thread-safe? If not, how can that be achieved?

I do have code that seems to end up in a deadlock (far too large/complicated to post), which relies on the above to work fine in parallel calculations.

Comment: Does this DataClass have any other methods? If the shown code is the only code in this class, then the shown contents of `get_data` is thread safe.

Comment: There is no obvious error that I can see in the code shown.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik The real code is much more involved, but that particular `data` and lock are not touched elsewhere - the debugger tells me that all threads are stuck in the line where the `lock_guard` is created.

Comment: Thread safety is a relational property.  Two pieces of code (or the same code with itself) can be thread safe relative to one another.  The above code is thread safe relative to itself, except it is also guaranteed UB, because there is no way to populate the shared ptrs in question.  Code that manipulates said shared ptrs may or may not be thread safe relative to the above code.  For example, another thre running default copy ctor *writing* to the object would not be thread safe relative to the above code, but *reading* would.

Comment: Can you reproduce the deadlock with a short example?

Comment: Re. the apparent deadlock, are you sure a thread that already owns the mutex isn't trying to re-acquire  that mutex without first releasing it?

Comment: One simple way to debug this is that after acquiring a lock set a pointer, or something, that can be used to quickly pinpoint which thread owns the lock. Then when a deadlock occurs see what that thread is doing.

Comment: I was able to locate the bug I encountered; it is caused by using tbb and nested parallelisation. The code inside the `if` in my case was parallel code as well which led to the active thread occasionally picking the next task of the *outer* parallel loop and thus got stuck at the same line as the other threads, waiting for itself to release the lock. Using `tbb::this_task_arena::isolate` resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

> Are calls to `get_data()` thread-safe?

As long as `data_lock` is not modified after the initialization in the `DataClass` constructor, it is thread-safe. `shared_ptr` itself is not thread-safe beyond reference counting, meaning that if the pointer itself is modified, it must be protected with a mutex. If it remains constant (which you can ensure by marking `data_lock` with `const`) then multiple threads can read the pointer concurrently, including copying the pointer and incrementing/decrementing the reference counter.

> If not, how can that be achieved?

If you do have an instance where `data_lock` can be modified, you must protect it with a mutex lock or otherwise guarantee that the modification cannot happen while other threads are accessing the pointer. In this particular case this would probably mean to get rid of `data_lock` pointer and replace it with a mutex.

You should also take care to not allow the pointed object to be accessed after `data_lock` is modified. Remember that dereferencing `shared_ptr` returns a raw reference without incrementing the reference counter. If that `shared_ptr` is modified, the object it previously pointed to can be destroyed and the raw references become dangling. This can happen in a subtle way, e.g. a reference to the mutex may be saved in a `lock_guard`, so after you modify `data_lock` under the lock the `lock_guard` destructor will attempt to unlock an already destroyed mutex.